# Use Pi as simple GPU for PC?

Tags: gpu

I have seen some many examples of connecting an external GPU to the PI but I want know if the reverse is possible whereby the RPI GPU can be accessed via a PC. The use case is to use the PI as a poor man's BMC for a homelab server. In particular I am interested in a low power ryzen server in a 1U rack where the only PCIE space is occupied by a network card.

Comment: Which OS runs on your Ryzen server?

Comment: Linux based hypervisor (e.g Proxmox) but happy to do a full bare metal install of Ubuntu server or similar.

Comment: This is a basic function of the X11 windowing system of your Linux OS on the server. See **headless X** or **terminal server X**. You can access it through the network with almost any computer then, it's not specific to the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry Pi is a expensive choice for the basis of a IPMI/BMC device, especially considering **the whole point of IPMI is that it works without and completely seperate from the server OS, without configuration and drivers**. Specifically, Pi-based IPMI devices need *extra* hardware because of the missing consumer-grade video input: https://github.com/Fmstrat/diy-ipmi

**In stark contrast to IPMI devices, which can interact with BIOS and UEFI effortlessly**, the Pi can never become a IBM-compatible GPU since no BIOS/UEFI on the planet will recognize it as one.

Last but not least, **not a single Raspberry Pi does support PCI/Thunderbolt or AGP - at all**.